# Amplitude of microphone osscilation relationship to distance?

Tags: acoustics

If I play a middle C on a violin then alternating wavefronts of high and low pressure air emanate away at some frequency about 200 Hz.

If I position a microphone at some distance away from the violin then the piston/drum in the microphone will ossicilate at the same frequency as it is disturbed by these wavefronts.

Let's say at distance $d_1$ meters away the amplitude of the microphones drum ossicilations is $l_1$ meters.

If I move the microphone to a new distance $d_2$ meters away from the violin, what would you expect the new amplitude of its drums ossicilation to be in terms of $d_1$, $d_2$ and $l_1$ ?

Comment: That would depend on the radiation pattern of your violin. This, indeed, varies with the note you play. I suppose that the radiation pattern is close to a sphere, but I'm not sure, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real-world answer can be very complicated! But if the violin is isolated (far from other objects) and if the air is uniform and if the microphone is far from the violin (compared to the violin's size), then, in a given direction, the microphone excitation in power will decay as the inverse square of distance. The corresponding microphone amplitude will decay inversely with distance. So l<sub>2</sub> = l<sub>1</sub>*d<sub>1</sub>/d<sub>2</sub>.

Comment: So the "power" decays inverse square with distance, but the amplitude decays linearly inverse with distance.  Is the amplitude, therefore, square of the power?

Comment: Ok, got it now:  Power of a mechanical wave is square of amplitude and square of frequency:  https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/16-4-energy-and-power-of-a-wave